# How to distribute different types of values from one column into individual columns

Tags: sql, teradata

I have one table that stores different values in one column.
Lets say the structure is like:
`column_a`: name
`column_b`: contact_type - email or phone
`column_c`: contact_value - exact email address or phone number
Shall a person have both email and phone, there are two rows.

I trying to get a select that would distribute the different values into respective columns:
`column_a`: name
`column_b`: email_value
`column_c`: phone_value
One person should have exactly one row.

So far all my attempts ended one person having two rows - email address and phone null and vice versa...

Is there a way how to distribute the two values into two respective columns and have just one record for each person?

Hope it is not too confusing question...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use conditional aggregation:

```
select column_a,
       max(case when column_b = 'phone' then column_c end) as phone,
       max(case when column_b = 'email' then column_c end) as email
from t
group by column_a;
```